# For which value of $f(0)$ is a function continuous at zero?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

> **Question** Find the value of $f(0)$ so that the function $f(x)=
> \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt[3]{1+x}}{x}$ is continuous at $x=0$.

**My Approach** $f(0)= \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}x+\cdots+1+\frac{1}{3}x+\cdots}{x}= \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2+\left( \frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{3}x+\cdots\right) }{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}
\frac{2}{x}+\frac{5}{6}$

The book says that the answer is $\frac{5}{6}$; I cannot understand how.

Comment: You are correct. The sign between the two roots is probably wrong. Try calculating the limit using minus instead

Comment: @b00nheT30 taking the minus sign answer becomes 1/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of the assignment is wrong, because the function diverges as $x\to 0$: it's a $\left[\frac{\sqrt{1+0}+\sqrt[3]{1+0}}0\right]=\left[\frac20\right]$, after all! Perhaps - since the answer was supposed to be $\frac56$ - the person who wrote the exercise was thinking about the Taylor series $$(1+x)^\alpha-1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom\alpha kx^k=\alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}2x^2+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{3!}x^3+\cdots$$
and then she went blank for a second thinking that the $-1$ would cancel out.

Comment: Good answer but why are we assuming it's a "she"?

Comment: @jam I guess it's an issue with my English. In my mind, the pronoun which plays the subject of the second sentence should be a placeholder for the word "person" and, therefore, it should agree with the gender *of the word* (be it male, female or neutral). However, a "person" not being an object, I assumed that the gender could not be neutral, so I picked the one it has in my and other languages (female). Was "it" the correct pronoun? Or was it "he"?

Comment: @G. Sasselli as an Italian-speaking person, I completely understand the choice of "she". I actually personally don't like the form "he or she" as, to me, it sounds quite ridiculous.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Ah, I see - I think "they" would fit best :)